# Django queryset to list of dicts without duplication

Tags: django, dictionary, duplicates, django-queryset

I  have a following models

**Models**

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    DOB = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name


class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Manager, related_name='players')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

**Views**

```
def exportdata(request):
    q = League.objects.all().select_related("player")

    content = []
    for record in q:
        info = {
            'players': [record.player.name],
            'leaguename' : record.name,
            'country': record.country
        }
        content.append(info)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(content))
```

**Response**

```
[{
    "players": ["Roman"], 
    "leaguename": "La liga",
    "country" : "Spain"
}, 
{
    "players": ["Anthon"], 
    "leaguename": "Premier",
    "country" : "UK"
}, 
{
    "players": ["Xavi"], 
    "leaguename": "La liga",
    "country": "Spain" 
}, 
{
    "players": ["Ronaldo"],
    "leaguename": "Premier ",
    "country": "UK"
},
{
    "players": ["Zessi"],
    "leaguename": "Championship ",
    "country": "Spain"
}
]
```

I want list of players playing in specific league (without duplication) in a JSON format so i can parse the result from the angular. How can i achieve this? Expected response in following format:

```
[
    {
        "players": [{"id" : 12,  "name": "Roman"}, {"id" : 150,  "name": "Xavi"}], 
        "leaguename": "La liga (Spain)"
    }, 
    {
        "players": [{"id" : 98,  "name": "Ronaldo"}, {"id" : 9,  "name": "Anthon"}], 
        "leaguename": "Premier (UK)"
    }, 
    {
        "players": [{"id" : 19,  "name": "Zessi"}], 
        "leaguename": "Championship (Spain)"
    }
]
```

**What i tried**

```
def exportdata(request):
    leagues = League.objects.all().select_related("player")

    content = []
    players = []

    for league in leagues:
        # league doesn't exists so append it
        if not any(item['leaguename'] == league.name for item in content):
            content.append({"leaguename": league.name, 
                        "players": players.append({"id": league.player.id, "name": league.player.name})})
        else:
            # league already exists so don't append
            # players doesn't exists so append
            content.append({"leaguename": league.name, 
                        "players": players.append({"id": league.player.id, "name": league.player.name})})


    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(content))
```

Comment: Why not just return `q`? your for loop is the thing changing the format

Answer (score 0):

```
def view(request):
    leagues = League.objects.select_related('player')
    results = []
    for league in leagues:
        results.append({'leaguename': league.name,
                        'players': [{'id': player.id, 'name': player.name}
                                    for player in league.players.all()})
```

Comment: it should only append player (id, name) if **leaguename** already exists!

Comment: `for league in leagues:
        results.append({'leaguename': league.name,
                        'players': [{'id': league.player.id, 'name': league.player.name}])`

Comment: Have you tested it? It will create a dict for each league with a dict of their players inside them. Since we are iterating through League objects, they are unique. What is the problem?

Comment: Yes i have tested it! The problem is league name mustn't be duplicated. And `league.players.all()` is not a valid instance